# Showing $\sum_{g \in [a] }\rho(g) $ commutes - representation theory

Tags: representation-theory

I’m trying to follow part of a proof that just says a quick line but with no justification and I’m confused.

We have an irreducible matrix representation of a finite group $G$. Here $a \in G $ and $[a]$ is its conjugacy class. It just states that $\sum_{g \in [a]} \rho(g) $ commutes with any element in the image of $\rho$. My question, is why?

I have tried to show this as follows

$$\rho(g) \sum_{h \in [a]} \rho(h)= \sum_{h \in [a]}\rho(gh)$$ but I can’t really see how then it commutes since $g$ is any element in $G$.

Any pointers?

Comment: $gh=ghg^{-1}g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I continue your calculation like this:
$$
\rho(g) \sum_{h \in [a]} \rho(h)= \sum_{h \in [a]}\rho(gh) =
\sum_{h \in [a]}\rho(ghg^{-1}\,g) = 
\sum_{h \in [a]}\rho(ghg^{-1})\,\rho(g)\;,
$$
and I stop here, to enable you to perform the last step. You need to show that the r.h.s. of the above expression equals $\sum_{h' \in [a]}\rho(h')\,\rho(g)$, where $h'=ghg^{-1}$. To this end, you have to use the definition of conjugacy class.

Comment: So you just have to show that the map $[a]\rightarrow [a] , \ h \mapsto ghg^{-1} $ is a bijection for any $g \in G$, right?

Comment: @Anonmath101 Yes, it may be put like this.